# Remove selected rows on a button click in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a table with check box for each row .

I need to remove the rows for the selected check boxes in the table on a button click. (this button is outside ng-repeat).

The index of the selected rows are populated to an array using ng-change function  but i'm unable to remove the selected rows on a single button click

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vigneshwar33/jpk547zp/)

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="approvalApp">
<div ng-controller="SimpleApprovalController" >
<table style="width:90%" border="5"  >
<tr>   
    <th><input type="checkbox" ng-model="CheckAllData" ng-    change="selectAll()" /></th>
    <th>Date</th>
   <th>AssociateID</th>   
<th>Check-In</th>
<th>Checkout</th> 
</tr>

<tr data-ng-repeat="approval in approvalitems">     
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="{{approval.ReqId}}" data-ng-model="approval.selected" data-ng-change="SelectDeselect($index)"/></td>
<td>{{approval.Date}}</td>
<td>{{approval.AssociateID}}</td>
<td>{{approval.CheckIn}}</td>
<td>{{approval.Checkout}}</td>

</tr>
</table>
<input type="button" value="Approve" data-ng-model="ApproveIndex" data-ng-click="ApproveRequest()" />
```

**Script**

```
    $scope.SelectDeselect=function(index)
    {
        $scope.getIndexvalues = [];
        angular.forEach($scope.approvalitems, function (approval,index) {               
            if (!!approval.selected) {
               $scope.getIndexvalues.push(index);
                $scope.CheckAllData = false;                 
            }              
        });

        console.log($scope.getIndexvalues);
    };

$scope.ApproveRequest = function () {           
        $scope.selectedIdsArray = [{}];          
        angular.forEach($scope.approvalitems, function (item) {                
            if (!!item.selected) { 
                $scope.selectedIdsArray.push({ Reqid: item.ReqId, Status: "Approved" });
                $scope.CheckAllData = false; 
            }               
        });           

    };
};
```

So how to use getIndexvalues in approverequest function , or is there any better way to remove it using other angular directive.
I'm a newbie to angular js .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jpk547zp/1/

```
$scope.ApproveRequest = function () {
    $scope.selectedIdsArray = [{}];
    $scope.approvalitemsNew = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.approvalitems, function (item) {
        if (!!item.selected) {
            $scope.selectedIdsArray.push({ Reqid: item.Date, Status: "Approved" });
            $scope.CheckAllData = false;
            item.hideThis = true;
            console.log($scope.selectedIdsArray);
        } else {
            $scope.approvalitemsNew.push(item);
        }
    });
    $scope.approvalitems = $scope.approvalitemsNew;
    $scope.getIndexvalues = [];
};
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply do

```
$scope.ApproveRequest = function () {           
  $scope.approvalitems = $scope.approvalitems.filter(function(i){
      return !i.selected;
  });
};
```

Comment: Thank you , but i need to remove the selected rows on the approve button click rather than the checkbox click.

Comment: then do the same thing on button's ng-click

Comment: but there is only one button present and its outside ng-repeat. Its like many rows with one button at the bottom of the table.

Comment: Thanks for the simple and effective approach. Unable to up vote now due to less score,